# Git print X like pattern when pushing

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am here mostly because I don't have the word to describe it to google.

When I `git push origin master` to Bitbucket, it worked but I got this in my terminal. (It's changing color each 4 lines...)

```
Censored@Censored:~/Censored$ git push origin master
Password for 'https://Censored': 
Décompte des objets: 317, fait.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compression des objets: 100% (317/317), fait.
Écriture des objets: 100% (317/317), 6.24 MiB | 1.29 MiB/s, fait.
Total 317 (delta 236), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: ++++                               ++++
remote:   +++++++                     +++++++  
remote:      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++     
remote:          +++++++++++++++++++++         
remote:                 +++++++                
remote:       +++                     +++      
remote:       ++++++     +++++     ++++++      
remote:        ++++++    +++++    ++++++       
remote:        +++++++    +++    +++++++       
remote:         ++++++++   +   ++++++++        
remote:          ++++++++     ++++++++         
remote:            ++++++++ +++++++++          
remote:             +++++++++++++++             
remote:              +++++++++++++              
remote:                +++++++++                
remote:                  +++++++                
remote:               +   +++++++               
remote:              +++   +++++++              
remote:             ++++++  +++++++             
remote:            +++++++   +++++++            
remote:           +++++++     +++++++           
remote:          +++++++       +++++++           
remote:          +++++++       +++++++           
remote:          +++++++       +++++++           
To https://Censored@bitbucket.org/Censored
f15...Censored...bc  master -> master
```

What is that ?

Comment: Maybe contact Bitbucket support?

Comment: What is what? The ASCII art? Or something else ?

Comment: @tadman that should be an answer

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason they're embedding the logo of [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com), the parent company of Bitbucket, in the output from their git server. I'm not sure why they'd do this, it seems obnoxious.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Atlassian logo done up in rainbow colors for Pride. You may see it on about 15% of pushes for the next little while.